# Redirected to searchfeedtech.com in Google search?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

I have experienced some weird issues using Google search recently. Sometimes when I search in Google, the search results are being redirected with the **searchfeedtech.com** URL.

I have only experienced this in the Google Chrome browser on my Windows 10 system.

In this screenshot, you can see that when I mouse over the result, the URL becomes `https://searchfeedtech.com`

[image]

I haven't installed any new extensions for Google Chrome.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue? If so, how can we get this fixed?

Comment: "I haven't installed any **new** extensions for Google chrome" - But do you have any existing ones? An update to one of those may be causing it. Try disabling your extensions and see if it still occurs.

Comment: Yes, I do have existing ones. Actually many existing extensions. But I know all these extensions. you mean maybe my existing extension are injected with some malware or virus?

Comment: It's possible. Disable them and we'll see if that's the issue. Then you can go through them one by one and see which is the culprit.

Comment: See here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome-es/gFw9sDM838c;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome-es/category$3Awindows-10%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false It's not in English but you can use Google Translate.

Comment: Thanks. If you post this in the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely caused by an extension. Even if you haven't installed any new ones, an update to one of your existing extensions may have been bundled with some malware, perhaps inadvertently or perhaps not.

Try disabling all extensions, and if the problem goes away, re-enable them one by one to see which is the culprit.

See here for someone with the same issue as you describe (It's not in English but Google Translate does a pretty good job): https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome-es/gFw9sDM838c;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome-es/category

Answer (score 15):

I was facing the same issue. In my case, the culprit was **Page Ruler** extension. I've removed it from my browser, and also reported it as abuse to Google.

At the moment, it seems it's been already removed from Chrome store.
It's URL - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jlpkojjdgbllmedoapgfodplfhcbnbpn - is not working anymore!

Comment: thank you! after I removed Page Ruler it stoping happening

Comment: mee too... Thanks a lot. sala, page Rular ki to...

Answer (score 3):

As also mentioned in the spanish thread, the 'Page Ruler' extension was for me the culprit. Deleting it fixed the problem immediately.